How to change color of Selected values from Combobox in LwC
I have this piece of code, i need to the change the color of the selected to red instead of black(which is default) How shall I achieve this?
<template>
    <lightning-combobox
            name="progress"
            label="Status"
            value={value}
            placeholder="Select Progress"
            options={options}
            onchange={handleChange} ></lightning-combobox>

    <p>Selected value is: {value}</p>
</template>


You can try using custom CSS which is suggested by most of the AI tools(ChatGPT), however, I have noticed these custom CSS doesn't always work consistently when used for LWC components; in such cases try using lightning design system (LDS) to build your custom combobox where the possibilities are endless.
